# WebDriverException generated from Webdriver.SendKeys in InternetExplorer on Selenium Grid

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-grid, selenium-iedriver

When I attempt to run my IE tests on the Grid I get this stack trace

[image]

If I run the tests locally off the grid things run fine. My chrome and firefox tests both run on the grid with no issue, it just seems to be IE. Not sure what other information would be helpful any advice is greatly appreciated.

Here is the log from the node.

[image]

Test Framework:

```
Selenium standalone server 2.53.1
Selenium.WebDriver 2.53.1 
Selenium.Support 2.53.1
Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver 2.53.1.1
NUnit 3.4.1
.NET 4.5
   C#
```

Node setup

```
Windows Server 2008 R2 6.1
IE 11
```

Comment: did you check that firewall allows that port to go through?

Comment: yeah was able to verify connection with telnet

Answer (score 0):

My issue was not that `SendKeys()` wasnt working it was actually that it was just typing so slow  `WebDriverException` was thrown before typing could finish. https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3072

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems when using the 64-bit IE driver.  Text entry is painfully slow.  Switching to the 32-bit IE driver solves this problem.